# Snowflake Partitioning Vs Manual Clustering

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 large tables in Snowflake (~1 and ~15 TB resp.) that store click events. They live in two different schemas but have the same columns and structure; just different sources.

The data is dumped/appended into these tables on a monthly basis, and both tables have a `time_id` integer field which represents days since `1999-12-31` the click event took place.

**Question** **is** -- Should I leave it up to Snowflake to optimize the partitioning --**OR**-- Is this a good candidate for manually assigning a clustering key? And say, I do decide to add a clustering key to it, would re-clustering after next insert be just for the incremental data? --**OR**-- Would it be just as expensive as the initial clustering?

In case it helps, here is some clustering info on the larger of the 2 tables

```
select system$clustering_information( 'table_name', '(time_id)')
```

---

```
{
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(time_id)",
  "total_partition_count" : 1151026,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 130556,
  "average_overlaps" : 4850.673,
  "average_depth" : 3003.3745,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 127148,
    "00002" : 0,
    "00003" : 0,
    "00004" : 0,
    "00005" : 0,
    "00006" : 0,
    "00007" : 0,
    "00008" : 0,
    "00009" : 0,
    "00010" : 0,
    "00011" : 0,
    "00012" : 0,
    "00013" : 0,
    "00014" : 0,
    "00015" : 0,
    "00016" : 0,
    "01024" : 984,
    "02048" : 234531,
    "04096" : 422451,
    "08192" : 365912
  }
}
```

A typical query I would run against these tables

```
select col1, col_2, col3, col4, time_id
from big_table 
where time_id between 6000 and 7600;
```

Comment: What queries are you running on this data? What clustering strategy would you choose, if you chose it? Is there any specific queries you want to improve performance for?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa  I am thinking I could utilize a
time based  clustering key to make it easier to dump the required subset of data into a temp table and then do all the heavy lifting against that temp table which I imagine being much much smaller. I could also cluster by time_id and domains since domains is a popular where clause condition, but I am not sure if that's going to incur a significant overhead. These tables don't get queried that often but when they do, the performance is really bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I leave it up to Snowflake to optimize the partitioning? Is
> this a good candidate for manually assigning a clustering key?

Yes, it seems it's a good candidate to assign a clustering key (size + update intervals + query filters)

> And say, I do decide to add a clustering key to it, would
> re-clustering after next insert be just for the incremental data?

After the initial reclustering, if you do not insert data belongs to earlier days, existing partitions would be in a "constant" state, so the reclustering will just process only the new data/micro-partitions.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-auto-reclustering.html#optimal-efficiency

> Would it be just as expensive as the initial clustering?

In normal conditions, it should not.

Comment: This is helpful! Just so I have a sense of cost and time, how long do you think it'll take to run the clustering?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly a long winded commend to the question on Gokhan's answer:

> This is helpful! Just so I have a sense of cost and time, how long do you think it'll take to run the clustering?

I would suggest you do a one off rebuild of the table with the `order by time`  verse leave auto-cluster to incrementally sort a table this large.

I say this as we had a collect of tables with about 3B rows each (there was about ~30x of these table), and would do a GDPR related PII clean up every month, that deleted 1 month's data via an UPDATE command, as the UPDATE has no order by the order was destroyed for about 1/3 of the table, which auto-cluster would then "fix" over that following day.

Our auto-clustering bill was normal ~100 credits a day, but on these days we where using ~300 credits. which is implying ~6 credits per table, where a full table re-create with a order by would maybe take a medium 15 minutes so ~1 credit.

Which is not deriding auto-clustering, but when a table gets random scrambled it's "a little at a time" approach is too passive/costly, imho.

But on the other hand is you cannot block the insert process for N minutes while you recreate the table, maybe auto-cluster might be your only option, that other other-hand to this if you are always writing to the table auto-cluster will back off a lot, from failed writes.. But this point is more the "general case details to watch out for", given as you state you do monthly loads.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `order by time_id` during table creation will force/hint Snowflake to partition it more efficiently?

Comment: if you do a `CREATE TABLE <with the replace option> AS SELECT from old table ORDER BY time_id` and time_id is your cluster id, then yes, you will have perfect clustering.

Comment: Also I was talking to a Snowflake performance engineer today, and the updating clustered tables ruining everything solution is in the works. So that will be an awesome once that gets to general release.